# Need to debug a swing app inside eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have created a new Java project and imported a number of swing related files.  Everything seems to compile fine but I don't know what are the steps to debugging a swing app from within eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Debugging a swing app is really no different than debugging any other Java application. Click on the debug menu (little picture of a bug on the toolbar) -> Debug Configurations... and choose Java Application.  You can select 'stop in main' if you want break as soon as the app starts, otherwise set breakpoints.

Happy bug hunting!

Comment: for detail have a look http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html